# Integrating sonata admin form inside symfony2 form

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

i would like to integrate a sonata admin form inside a symfony2.0.x form. Is it possible?

I though about creating a custom form model class and inject the needed sonata admin form i want to integrate into and also a FormMapper instance. Should this work? Am i at the right direction?

The whole picture is, i have a Multimedia entity which stores any uploaded file and then i'm able use this files anywhere on my app, so any file upload requires the Multimedia admin form in order to list, select, create new files, etc. So i've created a custom form for which i need to integrate multimedia sonata admin form into.

The form is called like this:

```
$formMapper->add(  'contingut', 'final_content_type', array() );
```

I would like to add Multimedia admin form into final_content_type.

Comment: Are you using sf2.0 or sf2.1 ?

Comment: Then you shouldn't tag your question with [tag:symfony-2.1] :)

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake on quick writting. :)